# Pattern Matching Against Anonymous

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do something like:

```
private val isOne = (x: Int) => x == 1
private val isTwo = (x: int) => x == 2

def main(x: Int): String = {
  x match {
    case isOne => "it's one!"
    case isTwo => "it's two!"
    case _ => ":( It's not one or two"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately... doesn't look like my syntax is right or maybe that's just no possible in Scala... any suggestions?

Comment: The answer of @m-z is correct, but just as example: http://ideone.com/bP1iCX

Comment: Ah yeah, I can see how that could be super nice in some situations.

Comment: Not what you asked but maybe what you're looking for: `class Extractor[A,B](f:A=>Option[B]){def unapply(a:A)=f(a)}; val isOne=new Extractor(x=>if(x==1)Some(()) else None}` ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't going to work for two reasons. First,

```
case isOne => ...
```

is *not* what you think it is. `isOne` within the `match` is just a symbol that will eagerly match anything, and not a reference to the val `isOne`. You can fix this by using backticks.

```
case `isOne` => ...
```

But this still won't do what you think it does. `x` is an `Int`, and `isOne` is a `Int => Boolean`, which means they will *never* match. You can sort of fix it like this:

```
def main(x: Int): String = {
  x match {
    case x if(isOne(x)) => "it's one!"
    case x if(isTwo(x)) => "it's two!"
    case _ => ":( It's not one or two"
  }
}
```

But this isn't very useful, and `case 1 => ....` does the job just fine.

Comment: Yeah... in my actual use case I'm not actually looking for the value so my example above was actually a little silly... see http://exercism.io/submissions/fa3707f5cea249589396c11ee9561707

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining a legit use case for pattern matching actual anonymous functions, but you can edit additional information into the question. My gut feeling is that it won't do what you're looking for.

Comment: Got a better solution thanks to your answer. Thanks!